# Can't creating a table with 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I am incredibly new to mysql or databases in general.  I am trying to create a table (which should be simple) and I keep getting an error which I can't find an answer to on this site or another.

```
CREATE TABLE statepark
(
state$id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
park$id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (state$id, park$id),
FOREIGN KEY (state$id),
FOREIGN KEY (park$id)
);
```

My error just says there is a syntax error near 'FOREIGN KEY (park$id))'.  Now I know it should be possible from other examples I saw, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I suggest starting [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key has to reference something -- it can't stand alone.

If you had another table called `state` with a primary key `id`, you might create the foreign key in `statepark` like so:

```
FOREIGN KEY (state$id) REFERENCES state (id)
```

Comment: So, I have a state table and a park table both with primary keys (id).

so it should be:

   `FOREIGN KEY (state$id) REFERENCES state (id),`
    `FOREIGN KEY (park$id) REFERENCES park (id);`

is this right?

Comment: @ViscousRandom Correct.